# imagemagick/graphicsmagick - rotate image without further processing/compression

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick

How to rotate an image with `graphicsmagick` and leave the compression/quality and do no further processing?

This command will increase the filesize

`gm convert input.tif -rotate 90 output.tif`

Comment: tif is not a lossy format. you WILL get a different file with possibly different compression levels, but the raw bitmap you can get out of that tif will simply be a 90degree rotated exact duplicate of the original

Comment: If I create a PDF file from the tif file and rotate it with `pdttk` then the filesize is unchanged

Comment: that's because rotation in a pdf is a simple matter of saying `rotate 90` or whatever in a particular spot. a rotated tif is actually rotated, and all pixels change their location.

Comment: ok, so a rotated pdf file leaves the images unchanged?

Comment: pdfs are postscript programs, basically. they don't have to modify the image, they just have to tell the pdf renderer to rotate the output.